# Blender 2.8 Transformation Constraint Problem

Tags: rigging

I added transformation constraint to a cube and target was an-other's cylinder rotation but instead of changing its location smoothly the cube jumps to final and start positions.The same cube changes its location smoothly when i set the source to location of cylinder.Is this a bug in blender 2.8 ?

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: if, in the Transformation constraint, the rotation of the cylinder is set to, let say, 0 and 90° and your cube location is set to, let say, -10 and 10, it means that if your cylinder rotates 0°, which means doesn't rotate at all, the cube will move -10 units... maybe that's what happening, and if it's the case, give your cylinder a rotation of -90 and 90°.

Comment: Added the test file. Moonboots it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you need to apply the rotation of your cylinder: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. As it was not aligned with the *Global* orientation, there was a confusion in the rotation orientation.

Comment: I applied all transfroms still problem occurs

Comment: indeed it doesn't fix it completely, this constraint is a bit hard to handle or it's bugged, I'm making some tries...

Answer (score 0):

It jumps because you don't have "extrapolate" enabled.  As you rotate the cylinder in world Z from 0 to 180, you interpolate from +1 to -2.5 world Z translation for the cube.  When you rotate just a tad bit more than 180, it flips over to -180, and you are suddenly back at +1 world Z translation.  If you enable "extrapolate" it will interpolate smoothly from +1 to -2.5 and then back.

Why 180, why 2.5?  When your constraint is set to 360 and 5?  Because constraints don't know about rotations greater than 180 degrees.  They only understand rotations as existing in the -180, 180 range.

Note that a transformation constraint for this kind of work is really less than ideal, both for the reasons described, and because Euler angles aren't really sets of 3 independent, separable numbers.  In order for the cylinder's world Z rotation to be measured, it has to be calculated from its existing transformation, and that doesn't always give you the Z rotation you expected.  It is usually far preferable to use drivers to do the things you can do with a transformation constraint-- although drivers aren't going to let you do things in world space.

This is pretty clearly an abstract situation, rather than any real-world problem you're encountering.  So I can't tell you what a good solution is-- I don't know what your end goal is.  If you need help with a specific, concrete problem, it's probably fixable, but peeps would need to know the actual concrete problem, rather than the abstraction of it.